# MySQL Password Validation - No previous passwords

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6, security, password

I wonder if there is any possibility to use the password validation for MySQL 5.6 (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/validate-password.html) to prevent for example the last 4 passwords.

The possibility to prevent a user from choosing a simple password but allow the user to always choose the same password seems to be a little bit odd.

Sadly I am not able to upgrade the MySQL server.

Comment: Are you talking about MySQL credentials or your app credentials? MySQL uses the authentication plugin only to control mysql.user table.

Comment: I mean MySQL credentials stored in mysql.user table.

Comment: Write your own API front end; don't let the users log in directly to MySQL.

Comment: Writing an API which has access to the internal mysql tables is no feasible solution for my use case.

Comment: Are you using the mysql.user table as a way to manage user accounts for your application? What's the use case here? Are you trying to implement domain-level password policies for db administrators?

Comment: All applications are managing their own users within their own database, but there are a few users which need direct access to the SQL server (you could call these accounts db admins) and for compliance these users have to choose a new password every 90 days. Also, they are not allowed to use one of the last 4 passwords. In the long run all user accounts which are not used by any application will be managed by an AD, but this could take some time.